# Did minority Rabbinic opinions in the Talmud have to hold by the majority?

Tags: halacha-theory

Talmudic discussions are filled with counter opinions from many Rabbanim. In a mishnah there may be several Rabbinic opinions on a specific halacha. After a psak is decided did the minority have to follow the majority le'maaseh? Is there a difference when the halacha is in favour of a 'group' e.g. Beit Hillel/Shammai, the 'school of X' or the 'Rabbanan'? i.e. I assume that, although their positions vary greatly, Beit Shammai and Beit Hillel actually practiced as their 'school of thought' taught.

Comment: I think that this was only a requirement if the opposing view was confirmed by the beit din hatzadik.

Comment: @mevaqesh what do you mean by 'confirmed'?

Comment: Ruled. See the first two chapters of hilkhot mamrim.

Comment: See Eduyot 5:6-7.